# Capturing the sftp and ssh login information in a Linux server

Tags: linux

I am exploring ways to capture all the incoming SSH and SFTP login information [ machine name and the user ] to my Oracle Linux 5.x server.

I am relying on the /etc/syslog.conf to capture this information.

Currently I am using /etc/syslog.conf as

```
# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

local1.info     /log_saves/FTP_LOG
local2.warning  /log_saves/FTP_LOG
LOCAL7.debug    /log_saves/SFTP_LOG
LOCAL7.debug    /log_saves/SFTP_LOG
```

With the above configuration, I am able to capture all the FTP logins to my server to /log_saves/FTP_LOG but the SFTP/SSH inf is not recorded in /log_saves/FTP_LOG or /log_saves/SFTP_LOG
Is there any way/alternative/demon I could utilize to capture the SFTP/ SHH information

Comment: Please clarify. What do you want to record? Just the login event, or the credentials?

Comment: I am looking to record the login event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log facility for ssh is `AUTHPRIV`. So you need the following entry in your /etc/syslog.conf :

```
 authpriv.*    /var/log/secure
```

You can change the log file location.

As far as the log level is concerned, you can change it in the sshd config file - `sshd_config` with the `LogLevel` parameter.

Comment: I'd better not shuffle the logs around, just set up to `grep(1)` them out as needed.

Comment: I have configured my /etc/ssh/sshd_config as "Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -f LOCAL7 -l INFO" and I have /etc/syslog.conf entry as "LOCAL7.debug    /log_saves/sftplog/sftplog" but it is not capturing the sftp-server events. But it does capture the sshd/crond/rshd/login events. Am I mssing something here